# Why is makepri.exe creating more than one Resources.pri file?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to create a Resources.pri file so that Windows 10 knows which images to use for my start tile on different resolutions. I'm following step 6 of MSDN's documentation linked below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx#Specify_images_for_scaling__localization__and_high_contrast

I have all of my logo images labeled according to their scale. These are their names in my Assets folder:

```
70x70Logo.scale-80.png
70x70Logo.scale-100.png
70x70Logo.scale-140.png
70x70Logo.scale-180.png
150x150Logo.scale-80.png
150x150Logo.scale-100.png
150x150Logo.scale-140.png
150x150Logo.scale-180.png
```

When I use makepri.exe manually, it creates three Resources.pri files instead of just one with all of the scaling information I want in it. These are the files generated:

```
Resources.pri
Resources.scale-140.pri
Resources.scale-180.pri
```

Resources.pri has information for the 80% and 100% scales, but the other two files contain the information for the 140% and 180% scales. Any idea why the larger scales are being separated out into separate files? I've included below my TestAppConfig.xml file and the commands I'm using the generate the files.

#### TestAppConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources targetOsVersion="10.0.0" majorVersion="1">
    <packaging>
        <autoResourcePackage qualifier="Language"/>
        <autoResourcePackage qualifier="Scale"/>
        <autoResourcePackage qualifier="DXFeatureLevel"/>
    </packaging>
    <index root="\" startIndexAt="\">
        <default>
            <qualifier name="Language" value="en-US"/>
            <qualifier name="scale" value="100"/>
        </default>
        <indexer-config type="folder" foldernameAsQualifier="true" filenameAsQualifier="true" qualifierDelimiter="."/>
        <indexer-config type="resw" convertDotsToSlashes="true" initialPath=""/>
        <indexer-config type="resjson" initialPath=""/>
        <indexer-config type="PRI"/>
    </index>
    <!--<index startIndexAt="Start Index Here" root="Root Here">-->
    <!--        <indexer-config type="resfiles" qualifierDelimiter="."/>-->
    <!--        <indexer-config type="priinfo" emitStrings="true" emitPaths="true" emitEmbeddedData="true"/>-->
    <!--</index>-->
</resources>
```

#### Command to create TestAppConfig.xml

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\makepri.exe" createconfig /cf %USERPROFILE%\Documents\TestAppConfig.xml /dq lang-en-US_scale-100_contrast-high /pv 10.0.0
```

#### Command to create Resources.pri

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\makepri.exe" new /pr %USERPROFILE%\Documents\CreateResources /cf %USERPROFILE%\Documents\TestAppConfig.xml /in TestApp /of %USERPROFILE%\Documents\CreateResources\Resources.pri
```

Any insight into this is greatly appreciated! Let me know if I can provide and further details.

Comment: what is the impact of having multiple .pri files? Is there something that you are trying to do that you are not able to?

Comment: That's a good question @karann. I'm trying to create this Resource.pri file for a large code base (Mozilla's Firefox), so I want to keep the complexity and file size to a minimum.

Comment: @karann it turns out that I need one Resources.pri file after all because files not named "Resources.pri" seem to get ignored by Windows. My workaround for creating just one file with a default language seems to break the tile as well. There are more details at this link if you're interested: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283909#c20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution, though I'm exactly sure why it worked/was required to create just one Resources.pri file. I found that setting the default language of all of the images allowed makepri.exe to add all of the image scales as resouces candidates to one Resources.pri file. For example, I found this file structure worked:

```
\Assets
    \en-US
        70x70Logo.scale-80.png
        70x70Logo.scale-100.png
        70x70Logo.scale-140.png
        70x70Logo.scale-180.png
        150x150Logo.scale-80.png
        150x150Logo.scale-100.png
        150x150Logo.scale-140.png
        150x150Logo.scale-180.png
```

I was clued in by this snippet of documentation:

> Note  We recommend that you mark the default language on string resource files (such as en-US\resources.resw) and the default scale on images (such as logo.scale-100.png), even if these files will not be localized nor multiple resolution images provided

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965372.aspx

Go figure.

I hope others find this helpful. If anyone has anymore insight on why makepri.exe works this way, I'd be curious to know more.

Answer (score 6):

I've just encountered this with languages rather than images, but removing this block from the auto-generated makepri config fixed it for me:

```
<packaging>
    <autoResourcePackage qualifier="Language"/>
    <autoResourcePackage qualifier="Scale"/>
    <autoResourcePackage qualifier="DXFeatureLevel"/>
</packaging>
```